# Bash script how read data from file or maybe is better way?

Tags: bash

I totally I don't have knowledge to create scripts but with internet help I made something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

title=$(echo "$1" | sed "s/.*\///" | cut -f 1 -d '.')

function _ask() {
    while [[ $url == "" ]]; do
        echo ; echo -e "Input url:" ; read -e url
    done
 }
   
 
 
napi.sh search -k movie "$title"
_ask

napi.sh subtitles "$url" 
napi.sh subtitles "$url"  > /tmp/napi.log
napi.sh download -e srt "$READ_DATA_DROM_FILE"


sleep 999
```

**My script use another script napi.sh, script is used to find subtitles for movies.
What I want? script napi.sh with my script after start looks that:**

```
00:0001 - wywolano o śro, 5 maj 2021, 12:45:47 CEST
00:0002 - system: linux, forkow: 32, wersja: v2.0.0
00:0003 - Wyszukuje tytul: [Excalibur (1981) BD UK]
  19779 | 1981 | http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-19779-1981-(2009)
  13495 | Wieki ciemne | http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-13495-Wieki-ciemne-(1981)
  27746 | Law & Order: UK | http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-27746-Law-Order-UK-(2009)
   5189 | Kumple | http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-5189-Kumple-(2007)
  18774 | Kochanki | http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-18774-Kochanki-(2008)
  15357 | Biuro | http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-15357-Biuro-(2001)
  58423 | Asy wywiadu | http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-58423-Asy-wywiadu-(2020)
  15308 | Być człowiekiem | http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-15308-Być-człowiekiem-(2008)
  34976 | Jay and Silent Bob Get Old: Tea Bagging in the UK | http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-34976-Jay-and-Silent-Bob-Get-Old-Tea-Bagging-in-the-UK-(2012)
  35344 | Wilfred | http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-35344-Wilfred-(2007)
  19853 | Queer as Folk (UK) | http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-19853-Queer-as-Folk-UK-(1999)

Input url:
http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-13495-Wieki-ciemne-(1981)
00:0001 - wywolano o śro, 5 maj 2021, 12:46:05 CEST
00:0002 - system: linux, forkow: 32, wersja: v2.0.0
00:0003 - Przetwarzam:  [http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-13495-Wieki-ciemne-(1981)]
Rozmiar:       1468035072 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:2ebe958c6f1db983a7a22fdcfc5cdd87
Rozmiar:       1395307380 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:89843122e1d233d2d0e6bf966b707f74
Rozmiar:        734074880 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:fb61d8bcfb14142bf184380c90cbd70f
Rozmiar:       1061522432 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:c5aaa2b20d24ee2e8153a1e952df4702
Rozmiar:       2277292422 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:c2ca7d292272b0c14f98aedb186df183
Rozmiar:        733765632 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:27476961bb0314d8ffd2646e323865da
Rozmiar:        734472192 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:b4e1646f2f1aaea7b0706465374c622c
Rozmiar:        735967232 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:ef1d7cf72f421893d457872b5f0c15f9
Rozmiar:        735129600 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:37ec592bd7388fc762e4bce600b4238a
Rozmiar:        733560832 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:145b3a0216d2e6ecf810978e2397b462
Rozmiar:       1250066888 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:867bab321abf50c9114dce79719af6a1
Rozmiar:        752467968 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:017b0aad2fe5bc5938761e25ad290cf9
Rozmiar:        734183424 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:22ea62fb37433b86b037e7a381c1f0c2
Rozmiar:        735377408 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:74bd128f43370c19c523ed55fe5c42b3
Rozmiar:        734951424 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:69a37cb8c3663d76d5a0ae74ea4678ee
Rozmiar:       1441703936 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:23a345afdac2076e5f5d53be5f515ba5
Rozmiar:       3852328960 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:cf5271e896a0a98f7c4b663f22276c78
Rozmiar:       2423563336 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:e4408adc30b42c640fd1ca03215b28d1
Rozmiar:       1469560832 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:536c8e31b27a1a6331cdc0cccb5cefba
Rozmiar:        727031808 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:7da638d72632cf9a2cb8f4ac98ad44c6
Rozmiar:        691881984 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:2eef089c47e5091662a434c2113da59b
Rozmiar:       1554518016 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:89efdd8992dff459ffc5af358fd63645
Rozmiar:       4286324736 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:b4e35f6b2e22e7caedc412a3ea386394
Rozmiar:       8417546913 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:7f2674de47d03b3d3f1cd47ca5bbb425
Rozmiar:        833752171 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:015ac59f6bc19df769f27fe2c5486dfa
Rozmiar:       7043121390 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:4eb951c03a5ec8072be536fe00fa19e2
Rozmiar:       3127886839 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:8199a5060de39177aee368d40153d4f8
Rozmiar:       3223524020 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:e9d92eff10a70e7b1e4ff513a62f8e5f
Rozmiar:       8415158898 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:eb1e4a2641962ac9d667cca8f81dbe90
Rozmiar:      19203384300 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:5900d69221c5332fecadd928d284dce7
```

**I wanna download all subtitles and I need read all data type from file /tmp/napi.log ? or maybe I dont need use file maybe data can be read without creating log file ?**

/tmp/napi.log

```
00:0001 - wywolano o śro, 5 maj 2021, 12:09:50 CEST
00:0002 - system: linux, forkow: 32, wersja: v2.0.0
00:0003 - Przetwarzam:  [http://napiprojekt.pl/napisy-13495-Wieki-ciemne-(1981)]
Rozmiar:       1468035072 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:2ebe958c6f1db983a7a22fdcfc5cdd87
Rozmiar:       1395307380 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:89843122e1d233d2d0e6bf966b707f74
Rozmiar:        734074880 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:fb61d8bcfb14142bf184380c90cbd70f
Rozmiar:       1061522432 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:c5aaa2b20d24ee2e8153a1e952df4702
Rozmiar:       2277292422 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:c2ca7d292272b0c14f98aedb186df183
Rozmiar:        733765632 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:27476961bb0314d8ffd2646e323865da
Rozmiar:        734472192 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:b4e1646f2f1aaea7b0706465374c622c
Rozmiar:        735967232 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:ef1d7cf72f421893d457872b5f0c15f9
Rozmiar:        735129600 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:37ec592bd7388fc762e4bce600b4238a
Rozmiar:        733560832 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:145b3a0216d2e6ecf810978e2397b462
Rozmiar:       1250066888 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:867bab321abf50c9114dce79719af6a1
Rozmiar:        752467968 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:017b0aad2fe5bc5938761e25ad290cf9
Rozmiar:        734183424 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:22ea62fb37433b86b037e7a381c1f0c2
Rozmiar:        735377408 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:74bd128f43370c19c523ed55fe5c42b3
Rozmiar:        734951424 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:69a37cb8c3663d76d5a0ae74ea4678ee
Rozmiar:       1441703936 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:23a345afdac2076e5f5d53be5f515ba5
Rozmiar:       3852328960 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:cf5271e896a0a98f7c4b663f22276c78
Rozmiar:       2423563336 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:e4408adc30b42c640fd1ca03215b28d1
Rozmiar:       1469560832 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:536c8e31b27a1a6331cdc0cccb5cefba
Rozmiar:        727031808 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:7da638d72632cf9a2cb8f4ac98ad44c6
Rozmiar:        691881984 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:2eef089c47e5091662a434c2113da59b
Rozmiar:       1554518016 bajtow | fps:     25 | napiprojekt:89efdd8992dff459ffc5af358fd63645
Rozmiar:       4286324736 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:b4e35f6b2e22e7caedc412a3ea386394
Rozmiar:       8417546913 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:7f2674de47d03b3d3f1cd47ca5bbb425
Rozmiar:        833752171 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:015ac59f6bc19df769f27fe2c5486dfa
Rozmiar:       7043121390 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:4eb951c03a5ec8072be536fe00fa19e2
Rozmiar:       3127886839 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:8199a5060de39177aee368d40153d4f8
Rozmiar:       3223524020 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:e9d92eff10a70e7b1e4ff513a62f8e5f
Rozmiar:       8415158898 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:eb1e4a2641962ac9d667cca8f81dbe90
Rozmiar:      19203384300 bajtow | fps: 23.976 | napiprojekt:5900d69221c5332fecadd928d284dce7
```

**I wanna put all napiprojekt:id to my script like this:**

```
napi.sh download -e srt napiprojekt:e9d92eff10a70e7b1e4ff513a62f8e5f napiprojekt:eb1e4a2641962ac9d667cca8f81dbe90 napiprojekt:5900d69221c5332fecadd928d284dce7
```

Thank you for help I hope someone understand me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your post twice, I think I understood you. The ***napiprojekt:id*** can be extracted with `grep -o 'napiprojekt:.*'`; the output of this can be inserted in the `napi.sh download` command line with backticks.

- variant with log file:

  ```
  napi.sh download -e srt `grep -o 'napiprojekt:.*' /tmp/napi.log`
  ```
- variant without log file:

  ```
  napi.sh download -e srt `napi.sh subtitles "$url"|grep -o 'napiprojekt:.*'`
  ```